# Virtualbox boots to terminal

Tags: virtualbox

Running Windows 10 host with Debian guest. After starting the VM from the VirtualBox Manager GUI, the VM window opens and loads. Then the screen goes to a terminal to enter my username/password, and the terminal is the only interface I have with the OS. In the past, I have used this exact VM with graphics.

I have tried changing the graphics controller to VboxVGA, VMSVGA, and VBoxSVGA, each with and without 3D Acceleration. The Video Memory is sufficient (80MB). It must be a different setting that I am missing.

How do I enable the graphics instead of the terminal-only interface?

Comment: Its likely not VirtualBox, but the configuration of your X windows system in Linux.  What happens if you type "startx" at the terminal prompt?

Comment: Thank you, @essjae. Yes, that was the issue. Everything works as expected. I will have to configure that correctly. Appreciate the help!